# How to tell if uniroot.all has failed to find roots

Tags: r

I am running `uniroot.all` from the package `rootSolve` in the following way:

```
All <- uniroot.all(fun, c(0, 1))
```

which for my equation usually gives me two roots:

```
All
[1] 0.1000000 0.9732628
```

Sometimes there are no roots, but how can I test on the next line in R that that is the outcome?  The result is the following:

```
numeric(0)
```

*is.nan*(All) and *is.null*(All) return FALSE.  I tried looking at the [man page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf)
and didn't see any mention of a flag for whether roots had been found or the number of roots found.  I would have expected NULL as the returned value in this case.

Comment: "some parameter settings" please add example where there is no root. We could check the `length(All) > 0`?

Comment: What's `uniroot.all`? Its not in my base R packages.

Comment: `uniroot.all` in package rootSolve? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rootSolve/versions/1.7/topics/uniroot.all

Comment: Yes, apologies for forgetting to state the package, question edited now.

Comment: I'll edit it a bit more - you still say "uniroot" where you are using "uniroot.all"

Comment: Thanks - that is even clearer, nice that you included a reproducible example in your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the length of the returned vector of roots. Here's a **reproducible example**:

Get roots of this:

```
> sinc <- function(x) ifelse(x == 0, 1, sin(x)/x)
```

Between 0 and 1 there's none:

```
> v = uniroot.all(sinc, c(0,1))
> v
numeric(0)
```

Test length:

```
> length(v)
[1] 0
```

Extend out and there's loads:

```
> v = uniroot.all(sinc, c(0,100))
> length(v)
[1] 31
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to check whether the vector of roots returned has zero length as suggested by @zx8754. Note that it is fastest to coerce `length(All)` to a logical rather than explicitly computing the comparison to `0`.

```
if(!length(All)) {
  #handle case when uniroot.all finds no roots
}
```